# Precise interpretation of the p-value

Tags: statistics

At the intuitive level, we know the p-value to be result that is at least as extreme as we've seen. For example, flipping a coin 20 times and observing 14 heads when our null hypothesis is that P(heads) = 0.5. We find that the p-value is sum of the probabilities from 14 to 20 heads : P(X >= 14) = 1 - P(X<= 13) = 1-binomcdf(20, 0.5, 13) = 0.057 where binomcdf represents the binomial cumulative distribution function of a random variable X (in this case the # of successes of heads) less than or equal to X = x. When we use the two tailed test we find that 2(0.057) = 0.1153 which exceeds an arbitrary level of significance at alpha = 0.05. This tells us that we fail to reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level.

Is it correct to say that 90% of the time "we are certain" that the coin will flip within two or more standard deviations away from the mean? Why couldn't I just say 100 - 0.1153 = 99.9% of the time "we are certain" that the coin will flip within two or more standard deviations away from the mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to say that 90% of the time "we are certain" that the coin will flip within two or more standard deviations away from the mean?

No, because given the same information (14 Heads) you should tell you one thing only. You cannot be certain "90% of the time" for something that just happened (14 heads). There is only one "time", and it is "now". (just like you cannot say "This morning, 90% of the time, I will have coffee" -- it makes not sense, you either have coffee *this morning* or you do not).

*Note* : Moreover, the standard deviation for 20 draws of a fair coin is

$$\sqrt{20\times 1/2\times(1-1/2)}=2.236,$$

thus $2\,\sigma$ is not integer (this is not a continuous distribution). Actually, being $2\sigma$ away from 10 is the same as being $\leq5$ or $\geq15$ which is 0.0413895 (as per binomial)... but this is true *only IF the coin is fair*. If the coin is not fair you CANNOT compute this probability (knowing that the coin is not fair does not mean you know its frequency of Heads, just that it is not 1/2).

But you do not know for sure if the coin is fair and, as a matter of fact, you will *never* be certain 100% that it is (or that it is not). Any coin, fair or not can turn 14 Heads (unless it has two Heads or two Tails of course). That's life!

Back to the p-value which means this, and *only this* : "IF the null hypothesis were true (fair coin, absolutely certain, 100% sure), there would be a probability $p$ of getting such an *extreme* observation" (for 14 Heads, p=11.53%). In spite of the way the p-value is often interpreted as a level of *confidence* or *trust* (or even worse, a probability of something being true), it is not the case.

The usual mistake about the p-value is confusing

$$p=P(\text{ extreme observation }\,| \ H_0)$$

with some "probability" that the coin is fair, i.e.,

$$P(H_0\,|\,\text{extreme observation}).$$

Think about the following situation : you got your coin examined by a physicist who tells you with pretty much 99,999% "certainty" that your coin will, in the long run, fall on H say 80% of the time (or whichever other probability you can imagine as long as it is neither 0 nor 1). Still, you do the test, get 14 Heads (it can happen) and get that p-value of 11.53% -- you cannot reject $H_0$ (fair coin). What do you think is going on? Either the physicist was right, $H_0$ IS wrong, and your experiment is unlucky enough that you fail to reject $H_0$, OR the physicist (which you should trust way more than a simple 20-toss experiment) was wrong, the long-term frequency is anything but 80%, and your experiment teaches you nothing (remember that "failing to reject" is NOT equivalent to "accept $H_0$".

There is quite a bit of discussion on the relevance of the p-value in experimental research. If you are interested this paper is a good starting point:

[Cohen. The Earth Is Round ($p<0.05$)](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~maccoun/PP279_Cohen1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> Why couldn't I just say 100 - 0.1153 = 99.9% of the time "we are certain"

Because that would be mixing percentages with probabilities. You could write either $1 - 0.1153 = 0.8847$, or $100\%-11.53\% = 88.47\%$

> Is it correct to say that 90% of the time "we are certain" that the coin will flip within two or more standard deviations away from the mean?

You are using a vague term "we are certain", put it in quotation marks, and then ask "is it correct"? OK, the answer: it is "correct".

It is *correct* to say that the probability of the number of heads being within two SDs of the mean is about 90%.